# Can I exclude static inputs(tied to a particular value) from being considered in toggle/expression coverage calculation in ncsim or modelsim?

Tags: verilog, code-coverage, cadence

I have a situation, where some inputs at DUT level are **static**(tied to one value) all throughout the simulation. My code coverage is reduced because these inputs will never see any toggling(being static).

Is there any way (tool specific or some simulation argument) using which I can exclude just these inputs from being considered in calculating code coverage?

I know, I can use a coverage control file and specify to deselect modules/instances there. But could I have the tool/code identify a static input and ignore it automatically?

Expert opinion is welcome.

Comment: You might refer to your simulator's user manual. Some pragma like the one `//VCS cover off` must be available. Or you may have to explicitly exclude them in GUI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are formal tools that generate the waivers for you: https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/questa-covercheck/